# How to convert Firebase Auth Class Component Lifecycle to Hooks useEffect in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, lifecycle, use-effect

im trying to convert the following class component's firebase auth lifecycle to hooks' useEffect method.

```
class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    user: null
};

unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

componentDidMount(){
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        this.setState({user: user});
    });
}
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
}
```

}

I tried to convert it with the following code, it seems to work but i'm not sure if it is the right implementation. There is a warning that says 'user' is assigned a value but never used. Should i change line 2 to: `$const [ , setUser] = useState(null);`

```
const App = () => {
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const unsubscribeFromAuth = useRef(null); 
useEffect(() => {
    unsubscribeFromAuth.current = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        setUser(user);
        console.log(user);
    })
    return () => {
        unsubscribeFromAuth();
    }
}, []);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) to return the authenticated user.

This hook can be reused in any functional component needing the authenticated `user` info.

```
function useAuthUser(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // no need for ref here
    const unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setUser(user);
    })

    return () => {
      unsubscribeFromAuth();
    }
  }, []);

  return user; // return authenticated user
}

function App() {
  const user = useAuthUser(someProps);

  return <div>{user}</div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, indeed custom hook is a better approach.